# What does .post2 in pytorch versions means?

Tags: pytorch

I was looking at torch versions
https://pypi.org/project/torch/#history

```
1.5.0
1.4.0
1.3.1
1.3.0.post2
1.3.0
1.2.0
1.1.0.post2
1.1.0
1.0.1.post2
1.0.1
1.0.0
0.4.1.post2
0.4.1
0.4.0
0.3.1
0.3.0.post4
0.1.2.post2
0.1.2.post1
```

And I found out that some versions have the suffix .post2 (or .post3, post4).

At first I thought it was a release made after the minor version X release already happened (postX), but then I saw 1.3.0.post2, so that doesn't seem to make sense.

Also, pytorch doesn't seem to follow semver.

What does postX mean?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like related to PEP-0440 and post releases: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#post-releases

#### Post-releases

Some projects use post-releases to address minor errors in a final release that do not affect the distributed software (for example, correcting an error in the release notes).

If used as part of a project's development cycle, these post-releases are indicated by including a post-release segment in the version identifier:

```
X.Y.postN    # Post-release
```

A version identifier that includes a post-release segment without a developmental release segment is termed a "post-release".

The post-release segment consists of the string .post, followed by a non-negative integer value. Post-releases are ordered by their numerical component, immediately following the corresponding release, and ahead of any subsequent release.

> **Note**
>
> The use of post-releases to publish maintenance releases containing
>   actual bug fixes is strongly discouraged. In general, it is better to
>   use a longer release number and increment the final component for each
>   maintenance release.

But I still don't know how pytorch uses post since it seems to jump some postN versions .